# I have a png as a button in Xcode but clicking on the empty part of the png doesn't trigger the button. How can i overcome this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, png

[image]

Clicking on the empty part of each of these buttons doesn't trigger any of them. I tried putting a clear button in front of the images instead but the selected animation no longer works.

Comment: try adding one background button behind the png and give the same action to bg button

Comment: @Harish doing that would prevent the actual image from showing the "being selected" darker colors animation

Comment: Have you changed the button's image view frame? In a quick test, using a png with transparency... the full button frame responds to a tap for me.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, turns out I had one of the views overlaying them

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode debug bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ6T1.png)

As you can see from above img, you may click the `Debug view hierarchy` button to check where is your `clear button` and is it on the right place.